# How do i define an api route in next js 14?

Tags: rest, next.js

I'm trying to build a simple REST api. I have a route.ts file inside of src/app/api/timetable folder. Here is my route.ts:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

type ResponseData = {
  message: string
}
 
export function GET(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<ResponseData>
) {
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Hello from Next.js!' })
}
```

So its just basic example from docs. When I call this endpoint at localhost:3000/api/timetable I'm getting TypeError: res.status is not a function.

I'm using app router, typescript has the version 5.1.3, next js is 14.0.3

I tried to place it inside pages folder (like page router), it didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the definition to

```
export function GET(
  req: NextApiRequest,
) {
  return Response.json({ message: 'Hello from Next.js!' })
}
```

There is no Response in the method definition.

Answer (score 3):

This does not work becasue Next 14 does not use `import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";`

You can redo it like this

```js
//app/api/test/route.js

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
 
export async function GET(request: Request) {
  return NextResponse.json({ msg: 'Hello from server' })
}
```

Im sure with this you get the gist and can take it from here.

Here is a full reference with explanation from their website

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-response#json

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I use this one is js and it works.

```
export function GET (req,res){
    Response.json({Msg:"your message"}, {status:200});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the folder

`src/app/api/timetable` -> `src/pages/api/timetable`